# Centerlized EMR System

Tags: emr, hl7, healthvault

Do we have any centralized EMR system available which contains all hospitals, physician and patient data?

We need to work on some portal where we need APIs of centralized EMR or something that maintains centralized data.

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These solutions sounds good:

- http://www.marand-think.com/ (look the demo)
- https://oceaninformatics.com/platform/

Comment: Thanks for Revert Rodrigo.